# Micro USB Dust Cover Insert?

Tags: usb, desktop-computer

My computer has to put up with a fairly dusty environment, and I am concerned about the long-term build up of dust and/or lint. One of the first ideas that came to mind is to use a plastic dust cover insert to protect against this. On second thought, I then became concerned about wear and tear on the port as I would need to take the dust cover out to use that port. I use that port roughly once a week. So I'm not sure if sacrificing port longevity (if substantial) would be worth the protection from dust.

Does anyone have any input for this matter?

Comment: The dust getting into a USB port is going to be nothing compared to the dust and crud buildup that will accumulate around the actively cooled components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dust might not really have much effect on your USB ports, but again can cause clogging in your fan and inhibit airflow, which will hinder proper ventilation of heat. To be on the safer side, you can cover your computer with a cloth whenever you're away, to prevent dust from falling on your computer directly.